# Rails 3 equivalent of proxy_owner Association target always empty or nil

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations

I rails 2 if you you had `object1.object2` ( object1 with association with Object2) you could use `proxy_owner` on `object2` to get `object1`. I saw that in rails 3 `@association` variable on `object2` was supposed to have the same result. In my case however it is always `nil`. I tried `.association(:association_name).owner` on `object2` and it's always `self` (i.e `object2` ) but `association(:association_name).target` is always nil or empty depending on the association type. Any idea how can i can to know object1 from object2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Write a method in object two and include this :

```
 owner = self.proxy_association.owner
```

This will return the owner.

A work around that i used was using an inverse of

```
class User < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_many :schedules, inverse_of: :user
end
```

Now the classes are bound both the ways.

Comment: It does not work in my case. I'm using rails 3.2.14. and the method is  not defined

Comment: I could be missing something but it doesn't work for me yet. So does Schedule.find(x).user.proxy_association.owner return Schedule.find(x) for you?

Comment: check this. Inverse of is just used to prevent another query fire. If has_many and belongs to is used you would neways have the mapping

http://gsusmonzon.blogspot.com.br/2011/09/rails-power-of-inverseof.html